# Mouse "click and drag" scrolling behaviour and CSS scroll-snap

Tags: javascript, css, animation, slider, scroll-snap

I'm building a simple slider animation that is controlled using native CSS scroll-snap and a scroll eventListener.
You can see a working example here: https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/10d5ad6a2d9bf2cbac8e8d2e289153fa
I'm trying to add a click and drag behaviour on desktop, unfortunately CSS scroll-snap doesn't work well when the scrollLeft value is updated via JavaScript.
It kind of works by setting `scroll-snap-type: none;` when the user starts dragging but remove the smooth snap animation.

I noticed that when simulating touch events in Chrome dev tool, the scroll animation works perfectly when using the mouse.
I'm wondering if it's possible to re-create the same kind of touch-events emulation that Chrome dev tools uses in pure JS.
Or if anyone managed to manually update the scroll position of a `scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;` element while keeping the snapping animation.

Edit:

Here is an updated version of the example with mouse events using

```
el.scrollTo({
  left: newScrollLeft,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
```

on the `mouseup` event, and toggling the scroll-snap property.

https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/b3bc58f943768f5276563ae7077e41e0?editors=0100

It's pretty close to what I want, but still missing the scroll momentum present when using a normal scroll gesture.